# Why do type specs in OTP repeat parameter names?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer, typespec

In type specs for the Erlang standard library, there are almost never any types in the spec until the `when` clause. For example, the spec for `lists:member/2` is like this:

```erlang
-spec member(Elem, List) -> boolean() when
      Elem :: T,
      List :: [T],
      T :: term().
```

instead of:

```erlang
-spec member(Elem :: T, List :: [T]) -> boolean() when
      T :: term().
```

Is there a reason for this? Are these two styles equivalent from the dialyzer's point of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done that way because the documentation that is generated from the specs looks better if done like that.

Comment: Thanks, Lukas. Are the two styles equivalent from the dialyzer's point of view?

Comment: Yes, they should be. You made a typo in your example though, so in the question the specs are not the same.